# How to run commands at lock screen on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

How can I set up Windows 10 so that every time the user locks the screen (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) then a list of commands are executed? Something like a command line operation, or execute a program, or close a program, or lock a bitlocker partition, etc.

Comment: Use Task sheduler, create a task with the trigger of "When station locks".

Comment: Most programs and commands can run in a lock screen state. Unless your machine automatically enable some protection modes（which may interrupt some processes）due to low battery power. Do you want to ask if some specific programs or commands can do that?